# Papa parse returning empty array for large csv

Tags: angularjs, papaparse

While this code works for smaller csv data, it doesnt seem to work for very large files.

```
function httpGetCSVSuccess(response) {
            console.log("Entered httpGetCSVSuccess ");
            var total = [];
            var out = Papa.parse(response.data, {
                header: true, dynamicTyping: true,
                chunkSize: 1024 * 1024 * 100,
                chunk: function (result) {
                    total.push(result.data);
                }
            });

            var merged = [].concat.apply([], total);

            $scope.grid.data = merged;
        }
```

Comment: What exactly is not working? The parsing (by papa) or the rendering (by angular)?

Comment: Papa.parse is returning an empty array for a valid reponse object. "result" is always an empty array

Comment: `Papa.. It can parse files gigabytes in size without crashing the browser`. Try to parse it in a clean project (without angular or anything else but Papa)